# jQuery Press Enter Not on Class

Tags: jquery, keypress, enter

I was wondering how to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> but NOT when a particular class exists on the element being targeted ?

```
jQuery("#input").keypress(function (e) {
       if (e.keyCode == 13 && jQuery('.classTest').not(this)) {
         //any item selected with enter EXCEPT which has .classTest
       }
   });
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P.S. use `.input`! ID's are for ONE element only.

### [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/DwfQP/1/)

```
jQuery(".input").keypress(function (e) {
       if (e.keyCode == 13 && !(jQuery(this).hasClass('classTest')) ) {           
               alert('enter!');                   
       }
});
```

Code used:
`!( $(this).hasClass('classTest') )`

! = not
[jQuery API .hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)